# Using a struct as a key for NSDictionary

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, swift

I'm trying to use a `struct` as a key in `NSDictionary`. According to documentation it has to conform to the `Hashable` protocol.
I did that, but I'm getting an error that `DateRange` does not conform to protocols `Hashable` and `Equatable`. How can I fix that?
Here is my code:

```
struct DateRange: Hashable {
    var startDate: NSDate {
        return self.startDate.timeIntervalSince1970.hashValue
    }

    var endDate: NSDate {
        return self.endDate.timeIntervalSince1970.hashValue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Hashable` protocol has a required property that you have to implement in your struct:

```
var hashValue: Int { get }
```

Implementing the hashable protocol doesn't mean making its properties hashable - it's the entire struct that has to expose the above property, where the returned value should ideally be unique and of course depending on the internal state.

Note that the `Hashable` protocol requires the `Equatable` protocol, which must be implemented as well. Example:

```
struct DateRange: Hashable, Equatable {
    var startDate: NSDate
    var endDate: NSDate

    var hashValue: Int {
        return self.startDate.hashValue + 37 * self.endDate.hashValue
    }
}

func == (lhs: DateRange, rhs: DateRange) -> Bool {
    return lhs.startDate == rhs.startDate && lhs.endDate == rhs.endDate
}
```

To calculate the hash I've used the sum of the `startDate` hash value plus the `endDate` hash multiplied by 37 (a prime number). This solution doesn't take into account overflows, something you should take care of to prevent runtime errors.

Comment: could you please write a working example?  I'm getting a bunch of errors when implementing comparator function

Comment: After all my problem was that I declared struct inside the class :) But your answer works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Antonio's answer, [here](http://swiftdoc.org/protocol/Hashable/)'s a link explaining the `Hashable` *protocol* quite nicely.